# Filter by REPEATED values in bigquery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

How to filter repeated values in bigquery using AND condition
for example
[image]

I would like to select values from column A when column B has both 11 and 22

The below query gives me if 11 or 22 exists but I need instead AND
So I should get Test 1 and Test 2 but not Test 3

```
SELECT columnA, columnB
FROM table CROSS JOIN UNNEST (columnB) as b
Where B in (11,22)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Scanning for values that satisfy a condition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning_for_values_that_satisfy_a_condition):

```
SELECT columnA, columnB
FROM table
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(columnB) AS b WHERE b = 11)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(columnB) AS b WHERE b = 22)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
select * 
from table t
where 2 = (
  select count(distinct val) 
  from t.ColumnB val 
  where val in (11,22)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]